# UWP TimedMetadataTrack Events are not firing

Tags: events, uwp, text-to-speech

I can not seem to get the a TimedMetadataTrack object to fire the events CueEntered or CueExited for SpeechCue events.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/1c719293b0bce1f952f617bc06c65bc8df6703fd/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis)? If not, please refer to that sample and check your own code to see if there're some issues. If you still cannot locate your issue. Since your post was so simple, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: BTW, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently this line is needed when registering for IMediaCue.CueEntered and IMedia.CueExited events (at least the SpeechCue implementation of the interface):

```
((Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlaybackItem)item).TimedMetadataTracks.SetPresentationMode((uint)index, Windows.Media.Playback.TimedMetadataTrackPresentationMode.ApplicationPresented);
```

This line is required to exactly allow the system to send the CueEntered and CueExited events that are being listened for.

Yet again, another case of Microsoft not fully documenting things in their API Documentation or Code Examples.